# Combine date and text columns in a new calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

Creating a new calculated field in a SharePoint List (Office 365) that combines a text (Region) and a date (StartDate) column. The Region field has a value "DFO" and the StartDate has a value of "8/3/2022", which the user selects from a calendar drop-down. The new field type is a "Calculated (calculation based on other columns)" type. However, the output doesn't show the date correctly, it looks like this "DFO_44776".

Any thoughts/suggestions? The calculated field code is:

```
=Region&"_"&StartDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this formula:

```
=[Region]&"_"&TEXT([StartDate], "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great

Answer (score 0):

Use formula for your calculated column like this:

```
=[Region]&"_"&TEXT([StartDate],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`). For example: If you are using German language for your SharePoint site

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thanks for the details :)

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with similar questions in  future.